# write to windows event viewer from sql server job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, event-viewer, sql-server-job

I am working with sql server 2012 and have some jobs set up on it to run at different times during the day. If the job fails I want to be alerted of such.

On the server I have some software the monitors the event viewer. I would like to set up my jobs to write to the servers event viewer if the job fails. I would like to write with event id 999 and level of error.

How can I set up my jobs to do so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use SQL-command [xp_logevent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186244.aspx)

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_logevent 60000, 'Test message', informational
```

but it does not allow you set "event id", you can set only "error number"

Or you can create "power shell" job step with something like:

```
write-eventlog System -source Server -eventid 12345 -message "I am a custom event log message"
```

and enter the job step only on failure action in prev step